# Blazor Using Rout Parameters as Method Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-blazor

On my Blazor component, I'm accepting a parameter:

```
@page "/plant/{PlantName}"
    @code {
        [Parameter]
        public string PlantName { get; set; }
        private TestGarden.Models.Plants pd = new PlantData().GetPlantInformation(PlantName);
    }
```

On the method "`GetPlantInformation`", it says for "`PlantName`" - `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Plant.PlantName'`

I can't make the property PlantName static or Blazor will not work. So how can I use this property as a method parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do but you could use `=>` instead of `=`

```
//                            added =>
private TestGarden.Models.Plants pd => new PlantData().GetPlantInformation(PlantName);
```

What you were doing is called [Field initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) and using the `=>` is called [Expression-bodied member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) (please someone correct me if the name is wrong).

The difference is that when you use `=>`, is like you were doing this

```
private TestGarden.Models.Plants pd 
{
    get 
    {
        return new PlantData().GetPlantInformation(PlantName);
    }
}
```

And once you get `pd`, it will return `new PlantData().GetPlantInformation(PlantName)`.

The reason why using `=` gives you the error is that you can't initialize a field with another field's value, but when using `=>`, you aren't initializing it, you will only execute `new PlantData().GetPlantInformation(PlantName)` when you get `pd`.

## Edit:

As other asnwers are pointing out, you could use `OnInitialized`.

But you need to understand why and when you should use `OnInitialized` or the `=>`.

You should use `OnInitialized` if `new PlantData().GetPlantInformation(PlantName)` will do something that could be async, like getting data from the database, because if you call that method in the getter of a property, and it takes time, it can freezy your component until the database returns the value.

If it returns something from the database or do something that could be asynchronous, use `OnInitialized`, otherwise, it's ok to use `=>` (Expression Body).

Also there is another thing...

If you use `OnInitialized`, `new PlantData().GetPlantInformation(PlantName)` will run only once, and if `PlantName` changes for some reason, the value of `pd` won't be updated.

If you use the `=>`, it will always run `new PlantData().GetPlantInformation(PlantName)`, but will always be using the current value of `PlantName` in the case it have changed.

So there is a lot to think on how you are going to get the value of `new PlantData().GetPlantInformation(PlantName)`

Comment: @MisterMagoo Not sure if my explanation is comprehensible, please feel free to edit if there is something to add to it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize TestGarden.Models.Plants with the non-static property PlantName . You should instantiate TestGarden.Models.Plants in order to initialize it with the property, and this should be done in OnInitialized{Async) method.

This:

```
  @code {
    [Parameter]
    public string PlantName { get; set; }
    private TestGarden.Models.Plants pd = new 
    PlantData().GetPlantInformation(PlantName);
 }
```

Should be done like this:

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string PlantName { get; set; }
    private TestGarden.Models.Plants pd;

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
     pd = new PlantData().GetPlantInformation(PlantName);
   }

}
```

Note: A usage such as this:  `private Plant plant => new Plant(PlantName);`, which works can be very limiting and you should use it with care, understanding what you do as it can lead to unwanted result. The preferable way is to define an object variable and then instantiate it in the OnInitialized{Async) method. This is the natural way to do it, lucid, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Blazor components are similar to C# objects but not the same... The framework adds a syntactical layer for creating and consuming them by means of what is called "lifecycle events".

For initialization you'll have to override the OnInitialized() method or its asynchonous counterpart OnInitializedAsync() (if that initialization need to access some async data store):

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    pd = await GetPlantInformation(PlantName);
}
```

This method call may be called only once, when component is created. For other lifecycle events please take a look to [Blazor lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1)